# How to Determine how similar two strings are (until a certain point)

Tags: python, string, for-loop, similarity

I have a list of strings `['49275', '49287', '69674', '43924']`

I want to see how similar they are to a certain value (lets say `'49375'` BUT once there is a difference, everything past the difference needs to be counted as NOT similar (even if they are)

So `'49375'` and `'49275'` should have a similarity of 0.4 NOT 0.8

I tried the code below but I am getting stumped and there must be a better way.

```
l = ['49275', '49287', '69674', '43924']
x = '49375'

listy = []
for i in l:
  for n in range(len(x)):
    if x[n] == i[0][n]:
      listy.append((n+1)/len(x))
    if x[n] != i[0][n]:
      break
```

I would like the output to be a list of similarity numbers, i.e: `[0.4, 0.4, 0, 0.2]`

Thank You!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  "I am getting stumped" is not a problem specification: show us the output you have, and where your inner process departs from what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  You just want to append to `listy` at the point where the characters do *not* match (i.e. before the `break`), or if the loop completes without a `break` then append 1.0.

Note also that you want `i[n]` rather than `i[0][n]` - the `i[0][n]` was giving you an `IndexError` because you were taking the first character and then trying to take character `n` from that.

```
l = ['49275', '49287', '69674', '43924']
x = '49375'

listy = []
for i in l:
    for n in range(len(x)):
        if x[n] != i[n]:
            listy.append(n / len(x))
            break
    else:
        listy.append(1.)

print(listy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
l = ['49275', '49287', '69674', '43924']
x = '49375'

listy = [0] * len(l)
for i, el in enumerate(l):
    for n in range(len(x)):
        if el[n] != x[n]: break
        listy[i] += 0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in range(len(x)):
    if x[n] == i[0][n]:
        listy.append((n+1)/len(x))
    if x[n] != i[0][n]:
        break
```

Above is your basic problem: you append a value to the list for *every* matching character, not merely the last one.  Also note that you repeat the equality test; this is unnecessary.  Make two changes: first, simply replace the redundant test with `else`:

```
for n in range(len(x)):
    if x[n] == i[0][n]:
        listy.append((n+1)/len(x))
    else:
        break
```

Second, wait until you exit this loop to `append` the value.  That will fix the problem of extra data.

The implementation is left as an exercise fro the student.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import takewhile


def calc_similarity(l, x) -> list:
    similars = list()
    len_x = len(x)

    for item in l:
        a = list(takewhile(lambda ele: ele[1] == x[ele[0]], enumerate(item)))
        similars.append(len(a) / len_x)

    return similars

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = ['49275', '49287', '69674', '43924']
    x = '49375'
    similarities = calc_similarity(l, x)
    print(similarities)
```

You can use takewhile from itertools

> Return successive entries from an iterable as long as the predicate
> evaluates to true for each entry.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile

Also as it enumerate, the first element is index and second element is value